# React Native openURL() not respecting deep links / universal links

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I have configured deep links & Universal Linking in my app (AASA, Assetlinks...). Let's say my Universal Link is https://example.com/profile. If I tap on that link outside the app, it opens correctly the app.

The issue comes when I use `Linking.openURL("https://example.com/profile")` inside the app. It opens the WebBrowser instead of opening in the app (since it's a universal link).

If I try to open for example instagram `openURL("https://instagram.com")`, it opens the instagram app (and not the web browser)...

The reason of this is because I have implemented the redirectURL, so if I send any link through the email and the user has to be logged in in order to access to it, then I redirect the user after he logs in.

Some months ago, this used to work correctly. This is happening on Android and iOS.

The same behavior happens if I use `expo-linking` package instead.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the screen instead of using `Linking.openUrl`. Use `navigation.navigate('profile')`

Comment: that's something I want to avoid. A workaround could also be replace https://example.com by my uri scheme... But I'm wondering why this used to work perfectly and suddenly it stopped...

Comment: Universal linking is valuable when outside apps or browser open links associated with your app. In case of navigation happens inside the app. Universal linking is irrelevant.

Comment: But normally, returnUrl is a link. How should I manage then the returnUrl after a successful login?